# Testthat local_mocked_bindings when not developing a package

Tags: r, mocking, testthat

I'm developing a shiny app and using testthat for unit tests. I have a folder with test that I run with `testthat::test_dir`. However, I can't figure out how to use mocking features because I get errors that I'm not in a package.
Example:
source file with functions:

```
base_fn <- function(){
  0
}

mocking_result <- function(){
  1
}
```

My test:

```
test_that("Mocking a function works",{
  local_mocked_bindings(base_fn = mocking_result)
  
  expect_equal(base_fn(), 1)

})
```

I keep getting an error `Error in` dev_package()`: No packages loaded with pkgload`. I've tried setting the .package argument to NA, NULL, "base", no help.
Can I use local_mocked_bindings if I don't want to format everything as a package? I've figured out I can use `with_mock` to achieve this, but from what I gather that function is superseded so I don't want it to become unusable in the future.

Comment: Facing the same thing just now. Would be interesting to understand whether or not these functions have been created to be used exclusively within a package or not.

Answer (score 1):

As I was facing the same issue, I asked the question directly on the `testthat` package repo, and the answer is that

> those functions only work inside a package sorry. I think the easiest way to solve your problem would be to put your R scripts in `R/` directory and your tests in `tests/testthat/` directory and add a minimal `DESCRIPTION`